# Adding a nested join 'in' Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to join a table based on a couple of constraints, one of which is "where a value is IN an array".

I have this code as part of a complext query builder:

```
    $query->leftJoin('product_variable_values as val_alias, function ($join) use($rule) {
         $join->on('products.id', '=', 'val_alias.product_id')
              ->on('val_alias.product_variable_option_id', 'in', '(1,2,3)');
    });
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
left join `product_variable_values` as `val_ingredients` on `products`.`id` = `val_ingredients`.`product_id` and `val_ingredients`.`product_variable_option_id` = IN where `products`.`product_id`
```

You will notice that there is an error in the mysql statement because I use `IN` as the operator which is not allowed.

Offending code:

`->on('val_alias.product_variable_option_id', 'in', '(1,2,3)');`:

Offending output:

`` val_ingredients`.`product_variable_option_id` = IN where `products`.`product_id ``

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it same as :

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$query->leftJoin('product_variable_values', 'products.id', '=', 'product_variable_values.product_id')
->whereIn('product_variable_values.product_variable_option_id', $array)
```